# laptop drivers installation problem with Ubuntu

Tags: drivers

I am using Ubuntu for the first time on an Asus laptop, with a DVD containing the Windows 7 64bit drivers for the laptop. How can I install these drivers on my laptop with the Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 0):

Windows drivers will not work on Ubuntu. Ubuntu uses the drivers provided in the Linux kernel. Everything *should* just work out of the box. With each new release of the Linux kernel more hardware is supported. It's generally a good idea to wait for a new release of Ubuntu to install on a new computer so that there is better support for the hardware.

There are a few special cases where a additional **Linux** driver may be needed:

- Discrete graphics (Nvidia, and ATI graphics)
- Wifi
- other hardware

Discrete graphics drivers are provided by Ubuntu through the additional drivers software (12.04). Wifi drivers are provided by the hardware manufacturer for Linux, or Ndiswrapper can be used with a Windows driver. Other hardware may have Linux drivers that are provided from the manufacturer for Linux.